# Create React app - React.js- Browser throwing CORS error when using Firebase Auth REST APIs

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, cors, google-identity-toolkit

In my React.js app, I was implementing authentication using Firebase REST AUTH APIs.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-create-email-password

My code looks like this:

```
export const signUp = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/signUp",
  async ({ resource, email, password, returnSecureToken }) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        `${BASE_URL}/${resource}:signUp?key=[API_KEY]`,
        JSON.stringify({ email, password, returnSecureToken }),
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
);
```

I am trying to make a request to `https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=[API_KEY]`

Request Header:

[image: request header]

But browser threw the following CORS error:

[image: cors error]

In Firebase Setting, the `localhost` domain is allowed!

[image: firebase setting]

I tried other resources to solve this issue! But couldn't able to find a solution!

Comment: I faced the same issue and realised that I was using this extension https://webextension.org/listing/access-control.html

Disabling it worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an issue related to your Firebase settings, it's a navigator security issue.

A request is sent to a domain `identitytoolkit.googleapis.com` which is completely different from your current app's domain (`localhost`).

One way to solve this is to use a proxy. Check [react proxy](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) for further details.

Comment: Could you please provide some code snippets!